# Ubuntu 14.04 - Automatically mount USB drive without clicking on it manually?

Tags: usb, mount, nautilus, usb-drive, drive

Running Ubuntu 14.04 on my Intel NUC and using it right now as a HTPC, running XBMC.

When I insert a USB drive, Ubuntu recognizes it and shows the drive in Nautilus, in the panel on the left.

But the USB drive is not automatically mounted, I have to specifically click on the USB device in Nautilus and then it mounts and shows me the contents.

But when I'm using it as my HTPC with XBMC, this gets annoying because then I need to close out of XBMC, mount the drive by clicking on it and restart XBMC.

Any setting that I need to alter so USB drives are not only recognized, but also mounted automatically?

Comment: what does this return, should be true. `gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.media-handling automount`

Comment: This does return true ;).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`sudo apt-get install usbmount`

> automatically mount and unmount USB mass storage devices This package
>   automatically mounts USB mass storage devices (typically USB pens)
>   when they are plugged in, and unmounts them when they are removed. The
>   mountpoints (/media/usb[0-7] by default), filesystem types to
>   consider, and mount options are configurable. When multiple devices
>   are plugged in, the first available mountpoint is automatically
>   selected. If the device provides a model name, a symbolic link
>   /var/run/usbmount/MODELNAME pointing to the mountpoint is
>   automatically created.

Comment: Mmm... now the USB does mount automatically, but XBMC does not show any message that a USB drive is inserted (when it should normally display a message like "Show files on this USB drive", etc...). But this does answer my question ;)